# How to fix broken partition process - lost space

Tags: macos, disk-utility

I've started to partition my SSD in my MacBook Air (2011). Somehow it get stucked in this process for quite a while. **I decided to stop it and restart my Mac.**

But now: **My allocated space on my hard drive is gone** (around 18 GB), but also: there is no second partition.

> What can i do to fix this?

EDIT: To make it more clear:

1. Starting to partition my hard drive
2. 1. partition was getting shrinked by 18GB
3. The 2.partition was not yet there
4. Paritioning failed

So: No second partition, no 18GB on my first hard drive.

Comment: what is preventing you to redo?

Comment: Redo? The space is gone from within the user interface. It must be there somewhere. I use the non-exisiting space to create another partition?

Answer (score 1):

Get a disk utility like drive genius or disk warrior.  Don't use that drive AT ALL until you do, any screwups where the OS will write to the drive could destroy your data.  Unless I am misreading something here.
If no data is present just use disk utility to repartition one large volume, if it fails your drive is probably fubar'd.